# How to override block of included template in Django?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have this structure:

```
{# base.html #}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{# page.html #}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% include "snippet.html" %}
{# and I also want somehow to redefine {% block snippet_content %} of snippet here #}
{% endblock %}

{# snippet.html #}
<bells_and_whistles>
    {% block snippet_content %}{% endblock %}
</bells_and_whistles>
```

I hope that the code is self-explaining.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it is not possible in the way you want to do it.

Your options are:

1. Create a `modified_snippet.html` inheriting from `snippet.html` and overriding the block and include it instead
2. Change your `snippet_content` block to a `{{ snippet_content }}` variable and pass its contents using `{% include "snippet.html" with snippet_content="My content" %}`. Of course this method is quite limited.